# WFFM 8.1 Upgrade - Namespaces removed from Sitecore.Forms.Mvc

Tags: wffm

Converting WFFM from 8.0 to 8.1, using MVC and came across an error after my build and deploy to my local environment.  Error appearing is one of our Views has the below in lines 1 & 2 which causes errors.

```
@using Sitecore.Forms.Mvc.Data.Analytics
@using Sitecore.Forms.Mvc.Extensions
```

When running, receive this:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Compilation Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource
>   required to service this request. Please review the following specific
>   error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Analytics'
>   does not exist in the namespace 'Sitecore.Forms.Mvc.Data' (are you
>   missing an assembly reference?)
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 1:  @using Sitecore.Forms.Mvc.Data.Analytics Line 2:  @using
>   Sitecore.Forms.Mvc.Extensions

I looked into the [Release Notes for 8.1](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Web%20Forms%20For%20Marketers/Web%20Forms%20For%20Marketers%2081/Web%20Forms%20For%20Marketers%2081%20Initial%20Version/Release%20Notes) and did not see any references to this namespace being broken.

I also opened up Sitecore.Forms.Mvc.dll file for 8.0 and compared with 8.1 in ILspy.  I did not see the namespace Sitecore.Forms.Mvc.Data.Analytics in the 8.1 version as it was in the 8.0 dll file

Any help greatly appreciated to resolve this issue.

Comment: The default MVC WFFM Views do not include these references. Is the error in a custom field?

Comment: The error is in a view in our project under Views / Form, file name Index.cshtml.  I'm continuing to look into.

Comment: Those `using` statements are not in the default index.cshtml file. I would double check you have not made customizations.

Comment: Thanks, you are correct.  I looked @ the upgrade files and they were in fact different.  The code was in our source control and have updated it, and published...

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for the assistance of JammyKam I was able to figure out the issue.  Basically we had some views in our source control (Views / Forms (also the EditorTemplate)) that were OLD and had references to:

- Sitecore.Forms.Mvc.Data.Analytics
- Sitecore.Forms.Mvc.Extensions

When publishing, the WFFM 8.1 views were overwritten with the WFFM 8.0 views that were in the solution.